# Remove All Columns where the last row is not equal to specific value x

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I have a data frame(DF) that is like so:

```
DF <- rbind (c(10,20,30,40,50), c(21,68,45,33,21), c(11,98,32,10,30), c(50,70,70,70,50))

10 20 30 40 50
21 68 45 33 21
11 98 32 10 30
50 70 70 70 50
```

In my scenario my x would be 50. So my resulting dataframe(resultDF) will look like this:

```
10 50
21 21
11 30
50 50
```

How Can I do this in r? I have attempted using subset as below but it doesn't seem to work as I am expecting:

```
resultDF <- subset(DF, DF[nrow(DF),] == 50)

Error in x[subset & !is.na(subset), vars, drop = drop] :
```

(subscript) logical subscript too long

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it. My sub setting was function was inaccurate. I used the following piece of code to get the results I needed.

`resultDF <- DF[, DF[nrow(DF),] == 50]`

Comment: `subset()` works too, your issue was only about the syntax for calling it with a logical column vector (its third arg, not its second). See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue with `subset()` was only about the syntax for calling it with a logical column vector (its third arg, not its second). You can either use `subset()` or plain logical indexing. The latter is [recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9860090/why-is-better-than-subset).

The help page `?subset` tells you its optional second arg (***'subset'***) is a logical **row**-vector, and its optional third arg (***'select'***) is a logical **column**-vector:

```
subset: logical expression indicating elements or rows to keep:
          missing values are taken as false.

select: expression, indicating columns to select from a data frame.
```

So you want to call it with this logical column-vector:

```
> DF[nrow(DF),] == 50
[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

There are two syntactical ways to leave `subset()`'s second arg default and pass the third arg:

```
# Explicitly pass the third arg by name...
> subset(DF, select=(DF[nrow(DF),] == 50) )
# Leave 2nd arg empty, it will default (to NULL)...
> subset(DF, , (DF[nrow(DF),] == 50) )
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]   10   50
[2,]   21   21
[3,]   11   30
[4,]   50   50
```

The second way is probably preferable as it looks like generic row,col-indexing, and also doesn't require you to know the third arg's name.

(As a mnemonic, in R and SQL terminology, understand that 'select' implicitly means 'column-indices',  and 'filter'/'subset' implicitly means 'row-indices'. Or in `data.table` terminology they're called i-indices, j-indices respectively.)